# What car-sharing options exist in Vancouver for foreign license holders?

Tags: car-rentals, vancouver

I will be traveling to Vancouver soon and would like to have the option of using the local car-sharing services. I have a valid EU driving license, an IDP and a credit card with a high limit, so renting and driving a car should normally not be an issue.

What car-sharing options in Vancouver would agree to sign up a foreign license holder? And what are their approximate prices as of 2017?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Get a certified translation of your driving record for the past 3 years (in addition to your drivers license and IDP) and you can register for any car-sharing company in Vancouver.

---

As of 2017, the options for car-sharing in Vancouver are:

1. [Car2Go](https://www.car2go.com/CA/en/vancouver/). They do allow foreign drivers, however you currently have to go through some hoops to activate your license:

   > If you have an International Driver's License, please send your current driving record for the past three years (in English or French). To obtain your driving record, you must contact the licensing authority of your country.

   Currently registering for their service is free and afterwards the following rates apply:

   [image]
2. [Evo](https://www.evo.ca/). Foreign drivers are likewise allowed if you produce a driving record from the past three years. However unlike Car2Go [they insist on a certified translation](https://www.evo.ca/FAQ#what-is-the-driving-record-scoring-criteria):

   > We will need a photo of the front and back of your license as well as a copy of your 3 year driving record. Please contact the driving authority from your licensing province or country and ask them to email or fax a copy of your 3 year driving record translated in English to records@evo.ca. Evo accepts certified translations (sorry, Google Translate doesn’t count).

   Once registered [their pricing](https://www.evo.ca/Rates) is similar to Car2Go's.
3. [Zipcar](http://www.zipcar.ca/vancouver) has the least restrictive policy as only a copy of your passport and driving license is required:

   > Once the application is completed submit a color copy of your driver’s license and a second ID such as your passport, by clicking contact us below.

   The only issue is that a physical card is required to access their cars, so it's not too convenient for short visits. However you can use Canadian cars if you have a Zipcar account in another country and you can also have the card shipped to your address abroad, so you can pre-register for the service if you apply a month before you travel.

   Their [rental fees](http://www.zipcar.ca/check-rates/vancouver) are about 50% lower than with the car-sharing companies above, however there's a small monthly fee you have to pay.
4. [Modo](http://modo.coop/) is the smallest car-sharing company in Vancouver, but they likewise accommodate foreigners. In order to register [you have to](http://modo.coop/foreign-driving-records/):

   > Depending on the license issuer, the format of your record will vary. You must provide the equivalent of your driver’s record and claims history (in English, if possible), and have them emailed to us directly at info@modo.coop.

   [Their current rates](http://modo.coop/plans/) are similar to Zipcar's pricing, however they have the advantage of allowing you to drive into the US, which is something other car-sharing companies generally forbid.